# Python rq loading flask app for every request added to queue

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, worker, python-rq

Am hosting apis through flask app, along with -

1. running on top are 2 gunicorn workers
2. flask tasks are queued using 2 rq workers

First I start 2 Gunicorn workers, and I get this message -

```
2020-10-29 07:54:21,992 : INFO : app : 140162149197632 : 17641 : Started app.py!
2020-10-29 07:54:22,078 : INFO : app : 140162149197632 : 17643 : Started app.py!
```

Then I start 2 rq workers -

```
2020-10-29 07:55:21,880 : INFO : rq.worker : 140051755202368 : 17743 : *** Listening on default...
2020-10-29 07:55:21,885 : INFO : rq.worker : 140281306085184 : 17746 : *** Listening on default...
```

But when I post a request to an api, my logs show -

```
2020-10-29 07:56:12,511 : INFO : app : 140162149197632 : 17643 : app.views : Added to queue. 0 tasks in the queue

2020-10-29 07:56:12,514 : INFO : rq.worker : 140051755202368 : 17743 : default: app.tasks.run_detections({'module': '_all_', 'folder_name': 'CL201029-d7794130-5375-44f6-8334-da9bc7...) (dc319268-c696-4a9c-95a3-1a7843f12ef8)

2020-10-29 07:56:12,719 : INFO : app : 140051755202368 : 17801 : Started app.py!
```

^ Here the app was initialized again.

Log format is - '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(thread)d : %(process)d : %(message)s'

My question is, after the task was added to the queue, in the same thread (140051755202368) **another pid was created and the flask was initialized again**.

Why is this happening? I want to preload the app in all the workers at the beginning and not load them everytime a request comes.

What am I missing here?

My code structure -

app

```
 1. __init__.py
 2. views.py
 3. tasks.py
```

Am starting gunicorn as -

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 run:app --workers 2
```

worker.py

```
import sys
from rq import Queue, Connection, Worker

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("rq.worker")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('worker.log')
formatter    = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(thread)d : %(process)d : %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

with Connection():
    qs = Queue()
    w = Worker(qs)
    w.work()
```

supervisord.conf - for running rq workers

```
[supervisord]

[program:worker]
command=python worker.py
numprocs=2
```

Then running

```
supervisord -n
```

Comment: Difficult to help without the code you are using, but I hope this might help, https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs

Comment: @abvarun226 thanks for your reply, I have referred Miguel's blogs but am still not getting this issue. Have added the code that am using to run the app and workers

Comment: I see, this app structure seems to work fine for me: https://github.com/abvarun226/flask-app-bg. Take a look and see if it helps